# Cannot run a simple application in Scala

Tags: scala

Given the following code:

```
import scala.io.Source

object Demo {

    def func():Unit = {
        for ( line <- Source.fromFile("C:\Users\Hen\Scala_workspace\Itay\src\Demo.scala").getLines() ) {
            println(line)
        }
    }

    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
        //var x=args(0).toInt;
        func();
    }
}
```

Why is the pathname marked as a compilation error?
Eclispe won't let me run it

Comment: Given that the best answer in Scala is different from that in Java, I'd recommend *not* closing this as a dupe of a Java post.

Comment: I thought there might be a dupe Scala question about escapes for regex. In favor of keeping Scala-inflected Q&A, someone commented elsewhere: "In Java you need to escape \ with another \... Unsure of the scala language."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try triple quotes around your path, so that scala will not interpret `\ + char` as special characters:

```
"""C:\Users\Hen\Scala_workspace\Itay\src\Demo.scala"""
```

Comment: easier: use the non-backslash way ```"/Users/Hen/Scala_workspace/Itay/src/Demo.scala"``` "C:" can be ommitted (it is the main drive name in windows, so root in unix style paths).